# Yahoo Callback Domain Issue

Tags: php, url, oauth, callback, yahoo-api

While creating a new app on Yahoo Developers Network the field (i.e. Callback Domain) is not accepting any URL having slash ('/') in it, but previously it is taking the URLs with slashes.

Error thrown:

> Application Create failed. Scopes creation failed when creating App:
>   507 - {"domain_name":{"errors":[{"code":2402,"message":"Invalid domain
>   name: mobile.local.com/"}]}}

My redirect URL contains path for a sub-page and it is not possible for me to remove all the slashes from my callback domain URL.

What can I do in such case?

Please help.

Comment: I get ```Invalid Developer Credentials received``` - Did you get that error by an chance? Can't believe it's so hard to just register an app lol

Comment: Ok I just created a new Yahoo account and I can now create/register apps. I think the key is to create a Yahoo account from scratch, don't use one the alternative login methods (ie: signing in via Google).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally after a lot of research i found out that you just need to provide your domain only in the call back domain field and yahoo will work fine.

When a request is received the domain of redirect uri in the request is matched with the value saved in callback domain field and if it matches then user data is sent on that url.